# Intermittent 403 response from django.contrib.auth.views.login()

Tags: django, django-views

Using django.contrib.auth.views.login() to process user logins I'm seeing 403 responses in a production environment. A second attempt to login succeeds after an initial 403 (when that response occurs).

I've begun to log all 403 login failures, capturing the POST payload and cookie values which shows that csrfmiddlewaretoken (the hidden form field value) and csrftoken (cookie value) don't match. It's intermittent and happens to many users.

The following decorators are all applied to the login function being used to proxy the django.contrib.auth.views.login() function: @ensure_csrf_cookie, @sensitive_post_parameters, @csrf_protect, @never_cache

What might be the causes of this problem?

Comment: Maybe that page was opened for a long time and your cookie expired.

Answer (score 3):

The [CSRF token is rotated after login](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/csrf/#why-might-a-user-encounter-a-csrf-validation-failure-after-logging-in).

If you open the login page in one tab, login using a second tab, then you'll get a CSRF error if you submit the form on the original tab.

Comment: Up-voted, though I don't yet know if CSRF token rotation is the cause of this particular issue. I'll inform and warn our users about this and update here when I'm more confident that this is or isn't the cause. Thank you!

Comment: For forms after a user has logged in we need to logout and re-login to re-produce this !!!